# Yii2: HTML select shows just 1 row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, yii, yii2

I have a problem with HTML selection in my Yii project. I have select options that are hidden, after I choose the country, the region select options are shown by the current country. The select show me only 1 row, when I scroll down in the select, I can see the right options for the country.

Does anybody know where can be the problem? Thanks

Here is my code:

HTML:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="region_id"><?= Yii::t('vo-card', 'Region') ?></label>
    <select class="form-control" name="region_id" id="select-region">
        <option value="" disabled selected><?= Yii::t('vo-card', 'Select') ?></option>
            <?php foreach ($region as $item) { ?>
                <option value="<?= $item->id ?>" data-country="<?= $item->id_cc_number_country ?>" hidden <?= $item->id == $request['region_id'] ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?= $item->region_name ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <?php if (isset($errors['region_id'])) { ?>
        <div class="text-danger"><?= $errors['region_id'] ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```javascript
$(document).on('change', '#select-country', function (event) {
    $('#select-region option:not(:disabled)').prop('hidden', true);
    $('#select-region option[data-country="' + $(this).val() + '"]').prop('hidden', false);

    $('#select-region option').prop('selected', function() {
        return this.defaultSelected;
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

[Here is the screen of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNnoE.png)

Comment: have you result 1 or more  for **console.log($('#select-region option[data-country="' + $(this).val() + '"]').length);**  ?

Comment: Yes i have 1 or more. When i scroll down in the region select, i see the option. But select is stucked into 1 row

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem is in this line:

```
$('#select-region option[data-country="' + $(this).val() + '"]').prop('hidden', false);
```

Note:
`$(this).val()` - this is the `value` attribute of the selected `<option>`, but not value of `data-country` attribute.
And you need to select all `<option>`s by `data-country`-filter.

Here is the corrected version of your code:
https://jsfiddle.net/m5ayf9sx/

Comment: Thanks, but it did not resolve my problem with select as html element

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrRegions = [];

    $(document).ready(function(){
        arrRegions = $("#select-region").children();
    });

    $(document).on('change', '#select-country', function (event) {
        var country = $(this).val();
        $('#select-region option:not(:disabled)').remove();

        $(arrRegions).each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('data-country') == country){
                $('#select-region').append($(this));
            }
        });

        $('#select-region option').prop('selected', function() {
            return this.defaultSelected;
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    });
```